# How can I use filepicker_field with from_tag instead of form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filepicker.io

I am trying to integrate Filepicker with a form in Rails that is using form_tag. All the examples and documentation ([here](https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-rails/blob/master/README.md)) are using form_for.

I obviously get an error when I use it like this (haml):

```
= form_tag(@form_params, id: 'abc', url:'/url') do
  = filepicker_field '@variable', 'field'
```

The error:

`undefined method filepicker_field' for #<Class...>`

I can't change my form structure. Is there any supported way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the documentation only form_for is supported.

Could you use a non active record model (http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model) or virtual attributes (http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised) to allow form_for to work for you?

Comment: I don't think any of those solutions work. For now I am using a view helper as a work around. Thanks.